# amcharts radarchart with two valueaxis starting at radius 50%

Tags: amcharts

**Summary**

In the RadarChart the assignment valueaxis2.renderer.innerRadius = new am4core.percent(50); is ignored. But why? Is that a bug?

In this [am4charts demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/radar-chart-visualizing-yearly-activities/) the weekdayAxis (Mon-Sun) does have an innerRadius assigned and it works. It is a CategoryAxis however.

**Details**

How would you modify the am4charts [provided tutorial](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/yjvOxK) for the RadarChart so that series 1 is using the outer 50% and series 2 the inner ring?

At the looks of it, it should be simple. Add a second value axis, bind series 2 to the axis and axis1 has radius=50%, axis2 innerRadius=50%.

But it seems that the

```
valueaxis2.renderer.innerRadius = new am4core.percent(50);
```

assignment is ignored. I have traced it with the debugger. It checks if via properties["innerRadius"] and therefore assigns NaN to it.

Relevant modifications in the code to reproduce:

```
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.radius = am4core.percent(50);
var valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis2.renderer.innerRadius = am4core.percent(50);
```

and

```
series2.yAxis = valueAxis2;
```

My question is twofold: Am I missing something or is this a bug? What would you do to get such diagram?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in this release of am4charts.

https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2484